# Java Xmodem only for sending file

Tags: java, xmodem

I need XModem in my project only for sending is there any solution I am stuck in my project.

Comment: Is the project to implement Xmodem? Doesn't look like it's too hard of a protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmodem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this: http://serialio.com/products/jxmodem.php

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I've been using their serial port stack for years.